# export multiple collection using mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

Iam creating a test environment on the same ubuntu server where my prod enviroment is hosted.

So i need to create a replica of the mongodb database iam using on the ubuntu server but add '_test' to the end of the name of the database. That is the reason i dont want to use mongodump.

1. what would happend if i export the prod db version and restore it on the same server with the same db name. Would it just override?
2. So to solve the problem i wanna export all the collection at ones and import all the collection at ones. Is it possible? If yes. How is this done? If no... does this mean i have to do an export/import command for every collection? This is do able for because i only have like 10 collections.
   Or is there a better way to solve my problem?
3. What does the mongodbexport.exe do? it came with the mongo db tools in the bin folder? when i execute it there seems like a metrics.interim was created. What is that?

Comment: You can use [mongodump - copy/clone database](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/program/mongorestore/#copy-clone-a-database) feature to create a backup of a database and restore it to _another_ database.

Comment: I have tried using mongorestore with ns from and ns to. But it wont work. I get 'duplicate key error collection' error. Can you help me? is it really possible restoring on the same server you dump:ed from with same name and values?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `mongoimport` and `mongoexport` on only one collection at a time.

You could use some bash script to simplify the task

Something like this :

```
database = ""
host = ""
coll = ""
username = ""
password = ""
for VARIABLE in "collection_1" "collection_2"
do
    echo VARIABLE
    mongoexport --db $database --collection $coll --host $host --username $username --password $password --out $collection.json
done
```